# Dropdown menu for subcategories

Tags: categories

This code shows all categories available and also the subcategories beautiful listed right below its suitable parent category. Is it possible to make a nested menu, so that when I click on the parent category the subcategories are scrolling down/ dropping down right below the parent category?

```
$args = array(
    'child_of'            => 0,
    'current_category'    => 0,
    'depth'               => 0,
    'echo'                => 1,
    'exclude'             => '',
    'exclude_tree'        => '',
    'feed'                => '',
    'feed_image'          => '',
    'feed_type'           => '',
    'hide_empty'          => 0,
    'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'orderby'             => 'name',
    'separator'           => '<br />',
    'show_count'          => 0,
    'show_option_all'     => '',
    'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
    'style'               => 'list',
    'taxonomy'            => 'category',
    'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' ),
    'use_desc_for_title'  => 1,
);

$list_categories = get_categories( $args );
echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "<div class='productsubmenu'>";
echo "<ul>";

foreach( $list_categories as $cat ) {

    $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
    $args2  = array(
        'child_of'            => $cat_id,
        'current_category'    => 0,
        'depth'               => 0,
        'echo'                => 1,
        'exclude'             => '',
        'exclude_tree'        => '',
        'feed'                => '',
        'feed_image'          => '',
        'feed_type'           => '',
        'hide_empty'          => 0,
        'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'orderby'             => 'name',
        'separator'           => '<br />',
        'show_count'          => 0,
        'show_option_all'     => '',
        'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
        'style'               => 'list',
        'taxonomy'            => 'category',
        'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' ),
        'use_desc_for_title'  => 1,
    );


    if( $cat->category_parent == 0 ) {

        $category_id = $cat->term_id;

        echo '<li class="parentss"><a href="'.get_term_link( $cat ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a>';


        $subcats = get_categories( $args2 );
        echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';

        foreach( $subcats as $sc ) {

            $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
            echo '<li class="" ><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
            var_dump( cat_is_ancestor_of($cat_id,32));
            var_dump( $cat_id);

        }

    }

    echo '</ul>';
    echo "</li>";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create category listing functionality, WordPress already created a helper function to handle this easily. Take a look at [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/). And what you need can be achieved through some CSS and a little bit of JS if needed. You'll find lots of jQuery menu plugin you can use any of those or if you need a tree-like structure then check this https://www.jstree.com/